# RAD Server Lite does not install on Linux

Tags: linux, delphi, interbase, rad-server

When installing Delphi RAD Server Lite on Linux CentOS 7 (RH 7 like), I get an error:

> [FireDAC][Phys][IB]-314. Cannot load vendor library [libgds.so or libibtogo.so]

**Steps taken :**

1. Installed Delphi 11.2 on Windows 10 machine --> OK
2. Configured PAServer for Linux CentOS 7 -- > OK
3. Copied EMS files
   from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\EMSServer`
   to Linux server and run `sudo ./ems_install` --> OK
4. Copied Interbase IBToGo files from
   `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Interbase\redist\InterBase2020\linux64_togo` to Linux server `/usr/lib/ems/` --> OK
5. Downloaded RAD Server Lite license from
   https://reg.embarcadero.com/srs6/promotion.jsp?promoId=572 --> OK
6. Copied license file to Linux server `/usr/lib/ems/interbase/license` --> OK
7. Started EMS server, first time run for setup, in Linux server
   `sudo ./EMSDevServerCommand -setup` ===> FAILED !!

After confirming the questions, the final result was an error message and EMSServer was not installed properly, see the results of `./EMSDevServerCommand` :

```
>start
EMS server configuration file not found. Run the configuration wizard?(y)
Set up Options 
Server Instance ()? 
DB file name (emsserver.ib)? 
DB file directory (/usr/lib/ems)? 
Sample data(y) 
Console User (consoleuser)?
Console Password (consolepass)?
----------------------------
Set up Options
Server Instance: <default>
DB file name: emsserver.ib
DB file directory: /usr/lib/ems
Sample data: True
Console User: consoleuser
Console Password: consolepass
DB file: /usr/lib/ems/emsserver.ib
Configuration file: /etc/ems/emsserver.ini
----------------------------

-  Continue with these options?(y)

- An error occurred when trying to load your InterBase license. Verify that you have entered
  valid connection parameters for the new database. Also verify that the Interbase server
  instance is running. [FireDAC][Phys][IB]-314. Cannot load vendor library [libgds.so or
  libibtogo.so]. Hint: check it is in the PATH or application EXE directories, and has x64
  bitness.
```

Comment: Sounds like something you should be contacting Embarcadero Support about.

Comment: Embarcadero provides free technical support for installation related issues. Open a support ticket there.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thanks for evaluating this. I'll ooen a ticket with them, but most of the time you guys answer here fast and precise.

Comment: @KenWhite, thks. Ok, I'll do it and depending on their return, I'll post here the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I have done the following and it has been solved:

```
cd /etc/ld.so.conf.d/
sudo nano interbase.conf 
add the line --> /opt/interbase/lib 
sudo ldconfig
```